# R: Equivalent of "Fixed Width Delimitation"?

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot-table, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language.

I have a column in a data frame that looks something like this (the column is a CHARACTER variable):

```
head(b$`New Col`)

[1] "1073680,,  781230,,  292455," "128485,,   62890,,   65595,"  "372475,,  184745,,  187730,"
```

- The first row contains a single element: 1073680,,  781230,,  292455,
- The second row contains a single element: 128485,,   62890,,   65595,
- The third row contains a single element : 372475,,  184745,,  187730,

**I want to split this column into 3 columns:**

```
  id    col1   col2   col3
1  1 1073680 781230 292455
2  2  128485  62890  65595
3  3  372475 184745 187730
```

I know how to do this in Excel (e.g. remove last comma, and then used "fixed width delimited" using double commas).

But can someone please show me how to do this in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same in R, with `str_remove_all` and `separate`. Here, I remove all commas, and separate by whitespace. Use `convert = TRUE` to convert the separated values to numeric.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(col = str_remove_all(col, ",")) %>% 
  separate(col, into = str_c("col", 1:3), convert = TRUE)

#   ID    col1   col2   col3
# 1  1 1073680 781230 292455
# 2  2  128485  62890  65595
# 3  3  372475 184745 187730
```

*Edit*: you actually don't need the first step, since `separate` convert the first occurrences of the pattern defined by the length of the `into` parameter (here, 3). It also chooses by default punctuation character(s) as the separator, so it is not needed to specify it.

```r
df %>%
  separate(col, into = str_c("col", 1:3), convert = TRUE)
#   ID    col1   col2   col3
# 1  1 1073680 781230 292455
# 2  2  128485  62890  65595
# 3  3  372475 184745 187730
```

---

Data

```r
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:3, col = c("1073680,,  781230,,  292455,", "128485,,   62890,,   65595,",  "372475,,  184745,,  187730," ))
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Maël's answer: if you're strictly after fixed-width separation, use `separate` with position indices instead of delimiter strings.

Your example data:

```
b <- structure(list(New.Col = c("1073680,,  781230,,  292455,", " 128485,,   62890,,   65595,", 
" 372475,,  184745,,  187730,")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

separate by fixed widths:

```
library(tidyr)

b <- b %>%
separate(col = `New.Col`,
         into = c('col1', 'drop1', 'col2', 'drop2', 'col3'),
         sep = c(7, 10, 17, 21, 27)
)
```

drop the garbage columns (containing the delimiters):

```
b %>% select(-starts_with('drop'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun. Another way:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(col1, sep = ",,  ") %>% 
  mutate(col = parse_number(col1), .keep="unused") %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID,
              values_from = col, 
              names_glue = "col_{ID}")
```

```
   id   col_1  col_2  col_3
  <int>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 1073680 128485 372475
2     2  781230  62890 184745
3     3  292455  65595 187730
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `base R`

```
df <- cbind(df[1],  read.csv(text = trimws(gsub(",+\\s+", ",", df$col), 
    whitespace = ","), header = FALSE, col.names = paste0("col", 1:3))
)
```

-output

```
df
ID    col1   col2   col3
1  1 1073680 781230 292455
2  2  128485  62890  65595
3  3  372475 184745 187730
```